# Eager loading on entry not reducing queries

Tags: templating, craft3, image, eager-loading

Using this snippet returns me 38 queries on my homepage without the Eager Beaver plugin.

```
{% do craft.app.elements.eagerLoadElements(
    className(entry),
    [entry],
    ['headerImage', 'image1', 'image2']
) %}
```

Without the above loading all three images with `.one()` gives me 33 queries.

Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not fully up to speed with Craft 3, but I don't understand why you are using the Twig do tag here in combination with that eagerLoadElements function. Have you taken a look at the Craft 3 documentation about eagerLoading?
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#app
That has some great examples and explanation on how to do eager loading in Twig.

Comment: I know how to do eager loading, but I wanted to take it to the next level.
Read more in this article about eager loading your entry.

https://nystudio107.com/blog/speed-up-your-craft-cms-templates-with-eager-loading.

Comment: It would be helpful to get an answer to your question if you tell people that you're using a plugin. This isn't default Craft functionality nor syntax. It's the EagerBeaver plugin from NYStudio107.

Comment: I'm not using the plugin, this out of the box Craft now, but I guess that before you had to use a plugin. He explains that later in the article.

Quote: Note that on Craft 3, you can do the exact same thing that the Eager Beaver plu­g­in does by using craft.app.elements.eagerLoadElements:

Comment: So are you actually _using_ the `entry. headerImage`, etc. anywhere? If you do the query without eager loading, subsequent db queries are lazily evaluated, so they won't be triggered until you actually try to access a relation.

Comment: Alright, sorry Thaoms. Didn't know this. Guess I skipped some parts of the article :) I'll be quiet now and try to learn something new here :D

Comment: @andrew.welch I did, test both headerImage.one() and headerImage[0]

Comment: So it's potentially possible that if you only have a singleton of the thing, that the extra queries need to set up the eager loading will cause this; I'd have to do some profiling to know for sure. So the TL;DR is use eager loading when it benefits you (when you're looping through a number of things), and don't when it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think eager loading will help in this case because you're trying to eager load fields with only a single relationship (asset). It's not the n+1 query problem eager loading is meant to solve.

If you had an asset field with multiple assets selected, you would see some benefit. But even then, if there are only a few assets, the small penalty of eager loading might not outweigh the small cost of queries for a few assets.

Bigger gains would come from [nested relationships](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#eager-loading-nested-sets-of-elements). For example, a set of related entries each with an asset for a thumbnail image.

```
{% do craft.app.elements.eagerLoadElements(
    className(entry),
    [entry],
    ['entriesField.image1']
) %}

{% for item in entry.entriesField %}
    {% set image = item.image1[0] ?? null %}
    {% if image %}
        {{ image.url }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, it might be worth noting that in your testing, it matters what data you actually use.

In my test, this produced 19 queries:

```
{% set asset = entry.headerImage.one() %}
{{ asset.title }}
```

But this produced 23 queries:

```
{% set asset = entry.headerImage.one() %}
{{ asset.url }}
```